# How can I update text each day on my webpage?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I want to have a quote at the top of my page, and it should update itself everyday, whether a user quits the browser or not.
I'm not asking anyone to write code for me - all I need is a headstart, as I'm a beginner. Should I use Ajax refresh for this?
Been studying Ajax for the past week and I just can't get the puzzle pieces to fit.
I understand that if I simply use the if/else javascript statements, my quotes would only update if a user had to keep my webpage open until the quote changes, and when he quits the browser it would start all over.
I'm at wits end trying to figure how to do this. 
What language should I use to replace the quote (I have a list of quotes in a separate .txt file) each day?

Comment: first thing to think about is: what are the conditions that these quotes should appear on the website? a random one each day? a specific each day of the week?

Comment: Dynamic content is usually driven by some server side processing, but not always. Where/how are you deploying this website? Are you going to use static HTML or a server side technology like PHP, nodejs, ASP.NET, Java, etc. etc.?

Comment: It's actually the interface for a Mikrotik Hotspot page. I'd like the quotes to display at the top of the page, and I don't mind if a random quote appears each day or if it appears in a numbered order. There should be no user prompt or button - it should auto refresh. I thought Ajax was ideal for this but it's not working out for me. @Cᴏʀʏ, most of the pages are html, but it uses the Mikrotik server to run the pages...If that makes any sense. Sorry :/ new to this!

Comment: Well, you ge tthe quotes from the file using ajax (because you studied, why not use it?), do the logic you want to do (Math.random, whatever...) and display. But they key point here is getting the quotes from somewhere.

Comment: "Ajax" is only ideal for this if you are asynchronously fetching your quote from some external API (a route on your server for example). You can also have a large list of quotes on your front end and pick one at random without fetching anything. You can also just have your server inject a random quote into some HTML on your page (not ajax).You have to decide what approach you want to take first.

Comment: not exactly, having all the quotes on a file in the frontend would polute the project. Having in a separate file "simulates" a database, in a more simple way.

Comment: @MatheusSilva The quotes would not display without a sort of prompt... It must be automated. The question is, is Ajax really the correct way to do this, if I don't want the user to do anything for the quotes to appear each day? Obviously I don't want them waiting 24 hours with their browsers open for the quote to change... It should be updated with each date that follows.

Comment: Yes, obviously that approach is not ideal, but it can occasionally be a good starting place for beginners, just like an external file simulating a DB which is also very not ideal.

Comment: @ArabianMaiden the logic you are going to do to show that is up to you. If you are going to see if it is sunday, if it still sunday or whatever to display X quote, is up to you. But you are going to need to fetch the quotes from somewhere.

Comment: I see what you mean... Thank you , everyone, for answering. I hope I can figure it out soon. Wish me luck :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to need a server side programming language if you want to implement a system like this consistently. It wouldn't be a hard system to create. Just have a MySQL table and every day INSERT a new quote if one isn't found for the day in question...

Cron Jobs are another possible solution but a bit unnecessary. You can store the quote of the day somewhere and every day run a script to update it to something else.

If you ONLY want to use JavaScript I would recommend storing a quote and date changed variable in window.localStorage then if the user requests a page on your site update it and add days to it. The user can still clear this though. This makes the quote different for every user of your site.